# How do i recover the packages in each lerna repository after i have deleted the node_modules from the sub folders?

Tags: reactjs, npm, yarnpkg, lerna

My Repository Structure is

```
codebook
-packages
  -clii
  -local-api
  -local-client
-lerna.json
-package.json
```

I installed local api to `clii` and `local-client` to `local-api` but for publishing i wanted to change the name of `local-api` and `local-client` so I changed `local-api` to `@codebook/local-api` and `@codebook/local-client`. And ran `lerna bootstrap`.
I was getting a  `npm ERR! code E404`. So i deleted the `node_modules` in each subfolders. I thought `lerna bootstrap` would link the new files as well as install the packages. But it is'nt working. And now all the packages are missing from each sub repositories. I can't do a npm install in each of this repositories. What should i do to install all the packages?

Comment: "I can't do a npm install in each of this repositories. What should i do to install all the packages?"

The way Lerna works is to not have to run `npm` commands in any of the subfolders. The `bootstrap` command will install public packages or symlink your local packages listed in `lerna ls` command.

Answer (score 0):

If you are changing the package name of an internal dependency that you have already added to other packages, you need to change that package name in the dependent package.json files as well. Unfortunately I'm not aware of a way to tell lerna to migrate or "rename" a dependency in the project.

So if you changed `local-api` to `@codebook/local-api` you need to go into the package.json for clii and update `local-api` to `@codebook/local-api` as well.

That said: In my experience, lerna bootstrap is pretty buggy and 404s a lot. I do not know why. All of my issues with it were solved by using lerna for *adding* dependencies, and yarn workspaces to *download and link* dependencies. The difference being, lerna just adds to the package.json file while yarn does the downloading and symlinking work.

So the process here would be to add `workspaces: ["packages/*"]` to your package.json and add new deps via the following commands:

```
lerna add @codebook/local-api --scope=clii --no-bootstrap
yarn install
```